# "application failed codesign verification" from a hybrid app

Tags: app-store, hybrid-mobile-app

I've created a hybrid app, and I'm getting the "application failed codesign verification" message when I try to submit to Apple.

I have built my binary with a Distribution Profile.

Not sure where to turn next. I built using vsnomad from VisualStudio 2012.

Any suggestions will be very welcome!

Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I'm sorted now. The answer here was that my Developer certificate wasn't the right one... It LOOKED like the right one, no question that here wasn't anything which on the surface was out of order. But Rob from vsnomad RDPd into my laptop and did something by creating a new certificate.

Not the useful answer I hoped to give but never mind, it works. There's so little about hybrid development online, this isn't adding to the knowedge much I'm afraid.